# Redirecting to a URL, IE 8 Ignores Fragment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, redirect, fragment-identifier

I have an MVC 3 project that uses fragments heavily to dynamically load content for different pages.  There are pages that post back to a controller to upload a file.  Once the upload is complete, I want to redirect the user back to the page they came from.  I have the return URL passed to the upload action and then redirect the user back to that page, once the upload is complete.

This works correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but IE disregards the fragment and I am taken back to the root page in my solution.  Below is the code I use to redirect the user.

```
public virtual ActionResult UploadFile(string returnURL)
{
    // Do some work here...
    return Redirect(returnURL);
}
```

Is there any way to force IE 8 to keep the fragment and behave like Chrome and Firefox?

If not, is there a standard way to work around this issue?

I have also reviewed Eric Law's [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/17/url-fragments-and-redirects-anchor-hash-missing.aspx) on https redirecting and fragments.  It offers some insights into how the fragments are handled by different browsers.

Comment: (1) when you are redirected back, does the url in IE address bar contain your fragment, and (2) can you show the client code that uses fragments for navigation?

Comment: (1) No, IE does not show the fragment in the URL after the redirect.  (2) The client side code doesn't seem to matter.  If I redirect to a stackoverflow url with a fragment in it IE drops the fragment, but Chrome and Firefox keep it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be up a creek on this one.  The URL fragment is not considered significant to URL uniqueness, such as when deciding whether to add a page to the browser cache or add a URL to the browser navigation history.

URL query is included in URL uniqueness classifications, but the fragment is not.

It may be that IE8 is redirecting to the URL with the fragment, but it is loading the root page (without the fragment) from the browser cache because the fragment is not significant for URL cache-equivalence testing.

One brute-force way to test this theory might be to purge the browser cache and mark all your pages as no-cache on the server and see if that changes the IE8 behavior.  If IE8 redirects to the desired page with the fragment intact when the pages are not in the browser cache, then this would confirm the theory.  This is only a testing scenario, not a solution for production deployment.

Comment: Unfortunately the no-cache setting did not affect the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have build a small application to reproduce it. It worked as expected in IE9 and Chrome.

I have two suggestions for you:

- If it is a caching issue adding a timestamp in URL could help. Try to build a URL like this:

`http://localhost:50173/Sample/?timestamp=26.07.2012%2021:11:00#myLocation`

- If it does not work a workaround could be to render a javascript at the end which will navigate:

`window.location = window.location + "#myLocation";`

Comment: I agree that IE9 and Chrome work, unfortunately, I have to deal with IE 8, which seems to have the issue.  I can't hard code the fragment in my js as it is dynamic based on the page the user was trying to hit.  A use case is that a user went to a URL, but their session timed out and they need to re-login.  Upon re-logging in, I want to take them back to the page they were on.